# jit-grunt: Plugin for the “clean” task not found

Tags: gruntjs, magento2

After running grunt clean in magento 2.1.3 root folder I get error

```
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "clean" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I tried `npm install clean` & `npm install clean --save-dev` but get the same error.

I looked at the url for static mapping, but it is not clear in the Magento environment what I should add where?

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
npm install grunt-clean --save-dev
```

or

```
npm install grunt-contrib-clean --save-dev
```

Please refer to `Gruntfile.js`

Comment: That works -thanks!  jit-grunt is not in gruntfile.js hence the confusion of how to follow the error